# Stores array in YAML

Tags: java, spring, yaml

How to store array in yaml and extract values from this array in the code? I tried like this:

```
report:
  interval: 3
  to:
    - somemail@gmail.com
    - somemail@somecompany.com
    - io.lab@hh.com
    - ...
```

Later in the code (Spring Boot) I'm trying to extract values into my array:

```
@Value("${report.to}")
private String [] recipients;
```

So, i'm expecting to get this array:

```
String [] recipients = new String[]{"somemail@gmail.com", ...}
```

But I get exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'report.to' in value "${report.to}"`

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer @hsadik. Good day

Answer (score 1):

Just suggesting, if it is not what you want, please feel free to ignore, no worries.

But maybe you can use something like

```
    @Value("#{'${report.to}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String>         recipients;
```

and in the property file:

```
report:
  interval: 3
  to: somemail@gmail.com,somemail@somecompany.com,io.lab@hh.com
```

If you get the list in your app, the conversion to array should be straightforward. Like:

```
    public String[] getRecipients() {
        return recipients.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Good day

Answer (score 1):

1. One way is to pass the elements as delimited list. Typically we have used comma and it works out of the box for String arrays.
2. Second way to use a List, then you will need to set the delimiter using Spring SPEL format... see example below.

YML

```
report:
  interval: 3
  to: somemail@gmail.com,somemail@somecompany.com,io.lab@hh.com
```

Class

```
Value("${report.to:}")
private String[] array;


@Value("#{'${{report.to}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> recipients;

@PostConstruct
void testList(){
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    for (String a : array) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: how have you written yml snippet? I am unable to preserve format.

Comment: @SauriBabu please try this online  yml editor https://onlineyamltools.com/edit-yaml

Answer (score 1):

Make your yaml fields comma-separated to parse it as array

```
report:
  interval: 3
  to: somemail@gmail.com,somemail@somecompany.com,io.lab@hh.com
```

Your Java code can be

```
@Value("${report.to}")
private String [] recipients;
```

---

OR

```
@Value("${report.to}")
private List<String> recipients;
```

Follow this link for more tips and tricks
https://youtu.be/NFQDqEhx2e0